# H2 DB Corruption: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 1936 not found [1.4.200/9]

Tags: database, h2, corruption, chunks

we are using H2 1.4.200 with Spring Boot 2.2.2 and are experiencing from time to time database chunk corruptions. Therefore the database is not usable anymore. We know that our database is corrupt since recovery leads to: "IllegalStateException: Store header is corrupt". We get the following stack trace on restart:

2020-02-20 08:21:28.900 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool(595) - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 1936 not found [1.4.200/9]"

General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 1936 not found [1.4.200/9]" [50000-200]

```
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)

at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)

at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)

at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:347)

at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:333)

at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:301)

at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:74)

at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:192)

at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:171)

at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:166)

at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:29)

at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:340)

at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:173)

at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152)

at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)

at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56)

at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:80)

at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:438)

at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:149)

at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:227)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1155)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:416)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:121)

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.setBeanFactory(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:155)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1818)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1783)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1503)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1467)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1358)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1245)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)

at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)

at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)

at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)

at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)

at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)

at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:459)

at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107)

at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:88)

at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:438)

at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)

at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)

at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)

at com.cenarion.svnplus.app.Application.main(Application.java:79)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)

at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)

at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)

at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 1936 not found [1.4.200/9]

```
at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.getChunk(MVStore.java:1230)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readBufferForPage(MVStore.java:1214)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPage(MVStore.java:2209)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readPage(MVMap.java:672)

at org.h2.mvstore.Page$NonLeaf.getChildPage(Page.java:1043)

at org.h2.mvstore.Cursor.hasNext(Cursor.java:53)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap$2$1.hasNext(MVMap.java:802)

at org.h2.mvstore.db.LobStorageMap.init(LobStorageMap.java:109)

at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:791)

at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:307)

... 165 common frames omitted
```

Before the corruption there was also another error which leads to the closing of the database. After the restart we get chunk problem above:

2020-01-31 08:13:49 database: flush

org.h2.message.DbException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]"

General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]" [50000-200]

```
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)

at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:347)

at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$1.uncaughtException(MVTableEngine.java:93)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.handleException(MVStore.java:2877)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.panic(MVStore.java:481)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1338)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1312)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.tryCommit(MVStore.java:1272)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2780)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:3290)
```

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]"

General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]" [50000-200]

```
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)

at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)

... 10 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]

```
at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950)

... 5 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.acceptChunkOccupancyChanges(MVStore.java:1612)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1433)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1334)

... 4 more
```

2020-01-31 08:13:50 jdbc[3]: exception

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Die Datenbank ist bereits geschlossen

The database has been closed [90098-200]

```
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:622)

at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)

at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)

at org.h2.engine.Session.getTransaction(Session.java:1792)

at org.h2.engine.Session.startStatementWithinTransaction(Session.java:1815)

at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:190)

at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:114)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)

at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390)

at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163)

at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104)

at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:197)

at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4350)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74)

at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1168)

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1033)

at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687)
```

...

```
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)

at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)

at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)

at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)

at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)

at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)

at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166.findDeletedOlderThan(Unknown Source)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)

at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166.findDeletedOlderThan(Unknown Source)

at com.cenarion.svnplus.commons.service.GutachtenService.lambda$initBinCleanup$0(GutachtenService.java:82)

at com.cenarion.svnplus.commons.security.SecurityContextAwareThreadPoolTaskScheduler.lambda$schedule$3(SecurityContextAwareThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:91)

at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)

at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]

```
at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1338)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1312)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.tryCommit(MVStore.java:1272)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2780)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:3290)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.acceptChunkOccupancyChanges(MVStore.java:1612)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1433)

at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1334)

... 4 more
```

Can you please help us with this issue?

Comment: I got similar error for a little another code lines, without any other suspect reason or error. It's the error from the newest h2 engine. Strange that h2 continued working, but the very important action was not completed, so that error is kind of critical in my case.

Comment: I had a similar issue which resolved when I switched to using a single MVMap. Maybe this helps. https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/373#issuecomment-460471683 
Other people had more luck with some settings mentioned in the ticket, and/or upgrading.

Comment: In my case the application crashed with the same exceptions. Strange/curious was that the database and the application worked fine for days until a restart, though the backup-db files that I copied in the two days before were already corrupted. The backup-db file three days before was OK. I guess that this is because H2 runs in-memory and does not regularly try to re-read the db file.

Answer (score 0):

Another piece in the puzzle: I observe the "chunk xxx not found" message with a corrupted H2 database file sometimes after a delete statement and sometimes after an update statement.

Here is some log output:

```
2021-03-24 11:10:31,752 INFO  [153] DELETE FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE WHERE ID = ? LIMIT 1
2021-03-24 11:10:31,760 INFO  [153] SELECT ID, X FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE WHERE ID= ? 
2021-03-24 11:10:31,800 ERROR [153] org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "Allgemeiner Fehler: ""java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]""
General error: ""java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]"" [50000-200]"
General error: "Allgemeiner Fehler: ""java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]""
General error: ""java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]"" [50000-200]"; SQL statement:
ROLLBACK [50000-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
at org.h2.engine.Database.throwLastBackgroundException(Database.java:2221)
at org.h2.engine.Database.commit(Database.java:2202)
at org.h2.engine.Session.rollback(Session.java:846)
at org.h2.command.dml.TransactionCommand.update(TransactionCommand.java:49)
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollbackInternal(JdbcConnection.java:1530)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:561)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcXAConnection.getConnection(JdbcXAConnection.java:106)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:236)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:199)
[...]    
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]"
General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]" [50000-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:347)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$1.uncaughtException(MVTableEngine.java:93)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.handleException(MVStore.java:2877)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.panic(MVStore.java:481)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1338)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1312)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.tryCommit(MVStore.java:1272)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2780)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:3290)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]"
General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]" [50000-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]
at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950)
... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.acceptChunkOccupancyChanges(MVStore.java:1612)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1433)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1334)
... 4 common frames omitted
2021-03-24 11:10:31,823 ERROR [153] org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Die Datenbank ist bereits geschlossen
The database has been closed [90098-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:622)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
at org.h2.engine.Session.getTransaction(Session.java:1792)
at org.h2.engine.Session.getStatementSavepoint(Session.java:1804)
at org.h2.engine.Session.setSavepoint(Session.java:915)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:244)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollbackInternal(JdbcConnection.java:1530)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:561)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcXAConnection.getConnection(JdbcXAConnection.java:106)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:236)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:199)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException [1.4.200/3]
at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1338)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1312)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.tryCommit(MVStore.java:1272)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2780)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:3290)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.acceptChunkOccupancyChanges(MVStore.java:1612)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1433)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1334)
... 4 common frames omitted
[...]
2021-03-24 11:10:48,826 ERROR [153] org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 337 not found [1.4.200/9]"
General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 337 not found [1.4.200/9]" [50000-200]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:347)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:333)
at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:301)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:74)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:192)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:171)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:166)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:29)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:340)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:173)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getJdbcConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:189)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:352)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getPooledConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:384)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:234)
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:199)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 337 not found [1.4.200/9]
at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.getChunk(MVStore.java:1230)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readBufferForPage(MVStore.java:1214)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPage(MVStore.java:2209)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readPage(MVMap.java:672)
at org.h2.mvstore.Page$NonLeaf.getChildPage(Page.java:1043)
at org.h2.mvstore.Page$NonLeaf.getPrependCursorPos(Page.java:1192)
at org.h2.mvstore.Cursor.traverseDown(Cursor.java:157)
at org.h2.mvstore.Cursor.<init>(Cursor.java:31)
at org.h2.mvstore.Cursor.<init>(Cursor.java:27)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap$2.iterator(MVMap.java:797)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.LobStorageMap.init(LobStorageMap.java:109)
at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:791)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:307)
... 159 common frames omitted
```